# Error running release React-Native apk FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules

Tags: react-native, gradle, expo, release

I generated the apk running gradlew assembleRelease.

When I try to execute the apk I get the following error:
2019-07-14 18:32:12.199 16842-16864/? E/ReactNativeJS: The Expo SDK requires Expo to run. It appears the native Expo modules are unavailable and this code is not running on Expo. Visit https://docs.expo.io to learn more about developing an Expo project.

```
2019-07-14 18:32:12.208 16842-16864/? E/ReactNativeJS: Module AppRegistry is not 
a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
2019-07-14 18:32:12.225 16842-16865/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
Process: com.testapp, PID: 16842
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: The Expo SDK requires Expo to run. It appears the native Expo modules are unavailable and this code is not running on Expo. Visit https://docs.expo.io to learn more about developing an Expo project., stack:
<unknown>@718:136
v@2:1489
d@2:949
o@2:435
<unknown>@717:5996
v@2:1489
d@2:949
o@2:435
<unknown>@716:241
v@2:1489
d@2:949
o@2:435
<unknown>@714:150
v@2:1489
d@2:949
o@2:435
<unknown>@691:154
v@2:1489
d@2:949
o@2:435
<unknown>@337:161
v@2:1489
d@2:949
o@2:435
<unknown>@335:229
v@2:1489
d@2:949
o@2:435
<unknown>@12:58
v@2:1489
d@2:879
o@2:435
global code@1715:4
at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:54)
    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:38)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:160)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192)
```

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2019-07-14 18:32:12.230 1637-4992/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.testapp/.MainActivity

After that, the app crash immediately.

This is the result of react-native info:
React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: Windows 10
      CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
      Memory: 3.67 GB / 15.89 GB
    Binaries:
      Yarn: 1.13.0 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
      npm: 6.9.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: Version  3.3.0.0 AI-182.5107.16.33.5314842